# If you misty step 30 feet straight up do you have time to attack a foe next to you before you start falling?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, movement, falling

On your turn, you misty step 30 feet straight up. Can you make an attack before you start falling, or will you immediately begin to fall?

For example, a player wants to reach a flying enemy to knock him prone, then feather fall safely to the ground. Is he in reach long enough for all his attacks to go through? Will he fall before he can cast feather fall? (He used his bonus action on to cast a spell, so only cantrips during his turn.)

Answer (score 18):

### It would be an appropriate use of a Ready Action.

We can bypass all the discussion about when you really start falling, using the mechanics offered by a readied action:

> When the trigger occurs, you can either take your reaction right after the trigger finishes or ignore the trigger. Remember that you can take only one reaction per round.

If you were to ready a melee attack, with a trigger for when you misty step, then you'll be able to use that melee attack **right after you misty step**.

To me this is an elegant solution by RAW that also contains some balance: only stuff that can be done by a Readied Action, cost your reaction... Your DM may also feel that disadvantage may be appropriate in this case.

As covered by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123507/do-you-get-extra-attacks-when-you-ready-an-attack-and-use-it-in-your-own-turn), since you are using your readied action on your turn for an attack, you can use the Extra Attack feature by RAW.

Comment: Advantage might be more appropriate than disadvantage: the target is likely not expecting this, and you just spent considerable resources.

Answer (score 7):

### Depends on your action speed.

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything says so, on p.77:*

> When you fall from a great height you **instantly** descend up to 500 feet. If you're still falling on your next turn you descend up to 500 feet at the end of that turn. This process continues until the fall ends.

Emphasis mine. When you fall from anything more than a couple of feet, you become subject to the falling rules. You get enough time to react to the fact that you're falling with a reaction (for things like Feather Fall) or time to react to the fact that you're landing with a reaction (for reducing damage), but there is no in-between time.

**You cannot do anything WHILE you're falling** unless you fall for over 500 ft. In that case, you have a round to do something before you fall another 500 ft, and again each time until you land.

Attacks taken as a reaction to you either having made it up that far or beginning to fall are possible.

### How you would make this work

On your turn,

- Ready an Attack Action to attack your target immediately after you Misty Step.
- Misty Step up 30 ft. to your target.
- Your Ready trigger procs, allowing you use your Reaction to take the Attack Action on your turn.

  - You get all your Extra Attacks because you are taking the Attack Action on your turn.
- You fall until you hit the ground, taking falling damage.

Comment: The Ready action is triggered as a Reaction, though, so I don't think you can "ready an attack action".

Comment: "First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the **action** you will take in response to that trigger, or ..." The Attack Action is an action. In fact, there are rulings about the Readied Attack Action specifically revolving around whether or not Extra Attack applies. Specifically, a Readied Attack Action only grants Extra Attack if it is performed on your turn. Reading an Attack is usually done by Rogues under the effects of Haste to leverage the Sneak Attack ruling that it applies once per turn, rather than round. You can Ready Attack actions.

Comment: I find this interesting enough to be a [question on its own](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123507/do-you-get-extra-attacks-when-you-ready-an-attack-and-use-it-in-your-own-turn). I would appreciate if you can answer there, specially quoting these specific rulings you mention, as I'm not familiar with them and I'm indeed interested.