# Can an Eldritch Knight use their Arcane Charge feature before falling?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, teleportation, falling

[This Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/if-you-misty-step-30-feet-straight-up-do-you-have-time-to-attack-a-foe-next-to-y) establishes that if you suddenly find yourself mid-air (e.g. by teleportation), you only have time to use a reaction before starting to fall (examples include casting [*feather fall*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feather-fall), or using a readied action if you previously took the Ready action set the trigger to something like "when I am teleported").

This question is a follow-up to that one specifically concerning the [Eldritch Knight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#EldritchKnight)'s 15th-level feature, **Arcane Charge**:

> At 15th level, you gain the ability to teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space you can see when you use your Action Surge. You can teleport before or after the additional action.

For reference, the [Fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter)'s Action Surge feature says:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can push yourself beyond your normal limits for a moment. On your turn, you can take one additional action on top of your regular action and a possible bonus action.

Now, the question:

**On their turn, a 15th level Eldritch Knight casts [*misty step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) to teleport 30 feet straight up. Because Action Surge is a "free action", can they activate their Action Surge and use their Arcane Charge to teleport another 30 feet upwards before starting to fall?**

Why the answers to the other Q&A do not answer this question:

- Using an Action Surge is not a reaction (thus it's not clearly possible to do it before falling, according to the other Q&A)
- Using an Action Surge is not an action or bonus action (thus it's not clearly **impossible** to do before falling, according to the other Q&A)
- In fact, an Action Surge is a "free action" (although no such game term actually exists in 5th Edition) whose only timing restriction is that it can only be done on your turn.

Comment: Also note that you cannot use Action Surge to cast *misty step* again in the same turn, as that would take a second bonus action, which the fighter feature does not grant.

Comment: @Szega I was not suggesting a second Misty Step from Action Surge,  I was suggesting using Arcane Charge, the Eldritch Knight's 15th level feature. As such I believe if I remove the extra examples and edit the question to ask about the speed at which you can use Arcane Charge, it will not be a duplicate.

Comment: Given that your concerns here are about using action surge (which you posit is a feature that can be activated at any time) I do think that the questions are distinct and not duplicate. I have reopened on that basis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## I would rule YES

Here's my reasoning:
As per the Q&A, you have enough time to perform a reaction before falling, but Action Surge is instantaneous. Therefore, from my reading, and from my love of "Rule of Cool" rulings, it's possible.

However, There's an argument to be made against this ruling, which I'll include for the sake of completeness: Arcane charge states "You can teleport before or after the additional action", which *could be interpreted* as the teleport being part of the action, in which case you *do not* have time to do so before falling. Personally, I think this line of reasoning is pretty weak, which is why I as a DM would allow it (teleporting before falling).

Comment: Now, if activating Action Surge is indeed instantaneous, wouldn't that mean that the effects of the feature would also happen at that time? Eg you would be able to teleport and take the additional action?

Comment: It doesn't matter how long Action Surge takes.  The teleport ability is tied to before or after the action granted by Action Surge.  You can Action Surge first thing on your turn or just before using the extra action (which could even be your first action IMO).  So the question is whether you have enough time between finishing your teleport and taking an action after that.  Rule of Cool + !(Micromanage each second of the turn) = I agree/YES.